# Webscraping - Selecionar texto de caixa 'Drop Down'

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rvest

Car@s,

Como eu poderia selecionar o texto de uma caixa "Drop Down" em um site com o `rvest`?

Seguem o link e o código:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

link <- "https://www.camara.leg.br/presenca-comissoes/votacao-portal?reuniao=63837&itemVotacao=10269"

html <- rvest::read_html(link)

html %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath= '//*[@id="dropDownReunioes"]') %>%
   .[[1]]
```

Com este código, obtenho um objeto `{html_node}` que é uma lista com a opção selecionada: "selected", o item 10.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A questão é: como posso fazer para acessar o texto desta lista?

Consigo acessar o texto com esse código:

```
html %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath= '//*[@id="dropDownReunioes"]') %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="dropDownReunioes"]/option[10]') %>% 
  html_text(trim=TRUE)
```

Mas, acabo indicando a opção no `xpath`, `"option[10]"`, o que não atende, pois não queria selecionar 'manualmente' a opção selecionada. Poderia fazer com o `str_detect()`, mas não consegui transformar o objeto `{html_node}` em dataframe.

Sugestões?

Answer (score 0):

Você já estava bem perto de conseguir, com esse comando eu consegui extrair um vetor com todos os itens da lista:

```
data_frame <- read_html(link) %>%  
  html_nodes("option") %>% 
  html_text(trim=T) %>% 
  .[1:10]
```

Se esta lista se atualiza com o tempo, só precisa mudar a seleção no final, para extrair tudo menos os 3 últimos `.[-seq(length(.), length(.)-2)]`

Adicionando `%>% str_split_fixed(" - ", 2)` no final, é possível transformar em um data frame